# WebRTC Experiment: Chrome windows audio not sync

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg, webrtc

I tried to make the audio work for Chrome using this [Git Repo](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-Nodejs), but I'm having a sync problem with video and audio. The audio finished playing earlier. The video seems to be correct. I noticed that when I play the blob, the audio is playing fast.

I was able to make the audio work by commenting the line the throws error in the condition that check if sampleRate is less than 22050 or greater than 96000 in RecordRTC.js.

I tried to adjust the sampleRate other values and noticed that If the sampleRate is low, the audio plays slow and if the sampleRate is high, the audio plays fast. I was able to make the audio and video somewhat sync but it seems the pitch of the audio becomes noticeable lower than the expected pitch.

I've also tried FFMPEG to adjust the length of the audio to match the video length, but didn't been able to make it work.

the extensions of the files that are uploaded to the server for Chrome are .webm(video) and .wav(audio).

Comment: heh. WebRTC has yet to become mainstream and heavily documented to be usable by everyone, but I upvoted this question as it's interesting and a step to a better documentation through troubleshooting.

Comment: There are no time stamps in the recording mechanism. So, of course there will be time discrepancies that increase over the length of the recording. The only sure fire way to sync them would be to time stamp them as you cannot guarantee the time it takes to grab a packet or frame.

Comment: Also, this really does not have much to do with webrtc but everything to do with the recorder that is implemented. It only grabs frames and audio packets from a JavaScript node and no sync attempt is made, so that is a flaw in that script not in webrtc itself.